# What is this undocumented state for ElasticSearch recovery?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an ElasticSearch index that I was using to store a whole bunch of data spread out across 2 data nodes. One of the data nodes accidentally filled up on hard drive space and caused ES to crash. When I cleared the drive (of extra stuff, I didn't touch the ES data folder) and restarted ES node, the index shards didn't recover. It knows there should be shards on this node, but the recovery logic seems to be stalled. Here is the full return from _recovery?human&detailed=true

```
{
    "events_v4": {
        "shards": [
            {
                "id": 3,
                "type": "EMPTY_STORE",
                "stage": "DONE",
                "primary": true,
                "start_time": "2018-09-26T17:35:35.275Z",
                "start_time_in_millis": 1537983335275,
                "stop_time": "2018-09-26T17:35:35.764Z",
                "stop_time_in_millis": 1537983335764,
                "total_time": "489ms",
                "total_time_in_millis": 489,
                "source": {},
                "target": {
                    "id": "wu_A6DNPSiqrg6JfzAW28Q",
                    "host": "10.8.81.41",
                    "transport_address": "10.8.81.41:9300",
                    "ip": "10.8.81.41",
                    "name": "wu_A6DN"
                },
                "index": {
                    "size": {
                        "total": "0b",
                        "total_in_bytes": 0,
                        "reused": "0b",
                        "reused_in_bytes": 0,
                        "recovered": "0b",
                        "recovered_in_bytes": 0,
                        "percent": "0.0%"
                    },
                    "files": {
                        "total": 0,
                        "reused": 0,
                        "recovered": 0,
                        "percent": "0.0%"
                    },
                    "total_time": "0s",
                    "total_time_in_millis": 0,
                    "source_throttle_time": "-1",
                    "source_throttle_time_in_millis": 0,
                    "target_throttle_time": "-1",
                    "target_throttle_time_in_millis": 0
                },
                "translog": {
                    "recovered": 0,
                    "total": 0,
                    "percent": "100.0%",
                    "total_on_start": 0,
                    "total_time": "471ms",
                    "total_time_in_millis": 471
                },
                "verify_index": {
                    "check_index_time": "0s",
                    "check_index_time_in_millis": 0,
                    "total_time": "0s",
                    "total_time_in_millis": 0
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 7,
                "type": "EMPTY_STORE",
                "stage": "DONE",
                "primary": true,
                "start_time": "2018-09-26T17:35:35.242Z",
                "start_time_in_millis": 1537983335242,
                "stop_time": "2018-09-26T17:35:35.481Z",
                "stop_time_in_millis": 1537983335481,
                "total_time": "238ms",
                "total_time_in_millis": 238,
                "source": {},
                "target": {
                    "id": "wu_A6DNPSiqrg6JfzAW28Q",
                    "host": "10.8.81.41",
                    "transport_address": "10.8.81.41:9300",
                    "ip": "10.8.81.41",
                    "name": "wu_A6DN"
                },
                "index": {
                    "size": {
                        "total": "0b",
                        "total_in_bytes": 0,
                        "reused": "0b",
                        "reused_in_bytes": 0,
                        "recovered": "0b",
                        "recovered_in_bytes": 0,
                        "percent": "0.0%"
                    },
                    "files": {
                        "total": 0,
                        "reused": 0,
                        "recovered": 0,
                        "percent": "0.0%"
                    },
                    "total_time": "0s",
                    "total_time_in_millis": 0,
                    "source_throttle_time": "-1",
                    "source_throttle_time_in_millis": 0,
                    "target_throttle_time": "-1",
                    "target_throttle_time_in_millis": 0
                },
                "translog": {
                    "recovered": 0,
                    "total": 0,
                    "percent": "100.0%",
                    "total_on_start": 0,
                    "total_time": "204ms",
                    "total_time_in_millis": 204
                },
                "verify_index": {
                    "check_index_time": "0s",
                    "check_index_time_in_millis": 0,
                    "total_time": "0s",
                    "total_time_in_millis": 0
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 1,
                "type": "EMPTY_STORE",
                "stage": "DONE",
                "primary": true,
                "start_time": "2018-09-26T17:35:35.261Z",
                "start_time_in_millis": 1537983335261,
                "stop_time": "2018-09-26T17:35:35.760Z",
                "stop_time_in_millis": 1537983335760,
                "total_time": "498ms",
                "total_time_in_millis": 498,
                "source": {},
                "target": {
                    "id": "wu_A6DNPSiqrg6JfzAW28Q",
                    "host": "10.8.81.41",
                    "transport_address": "10.8.81.41:9300",
                    "ip": "10.8.81.41",
                    "name": "wu_A6DN"
                },
                "index": {
                    "size": {
                        "total": "0b",
                        "total_in_bytes": 0,
                        "reused": "0b",
                        "reused_in_bytes": 0,
                        "recovered": "0b",
                        "recovered_in_bytes": 0,
                        "percent": "0.0%"
                    },
                    "files": {
                        "total": 0,
                        "reused": 0,
                        "recovered": 0,
                        "percent": "0.0%"
                    },
                    "total_time": "0s",
                    "total_time_in_millis": 0,
                    "source_throttle_time": "-1",
                    "source_throttle_time_in_millis": 0,
                    "target_throttle_time": "-1",
                    "target_throttle_time_in_millis": 0
                },
                "translog": {
                    "recovered": 0,
                    "total": 0,
                    "percent": "100.0%",
                    "total_on_start": 0,
                    "total_time": "460ms",
                    "total_time_in_millis": 460
                },
                "verify_index": {
                    "check_index_time": "0s",
                    "check_index_time_in_millis": 0,
                    "total_time": "0s",
                    "total_time_in_millis": 0
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 5,
                "type": "EMPTY_STORE",
                "stage": "DONE",
                "primary": true,
                "start_time": "2018-09-26T17:35:35.290Z",
                "start_time_in_millis": 1537983335290,
                "stop_time": "2018-09-26T17:35:35.784Z",
                "stop_time_in_millis": 1537983335784,
                "total_time": "493ms",
                "total_time_in_millis": 493,
                "source": {},
                "target": {
                    "id": "wu_A6DNPSiqrg6JfzAW28Q",
                    "host": "10.8.81.41",
                    "transport_address": "10.8.81.41:9300",
                    "ip": "10.8.81.41",
                    "name": "wu_A6DN"
                },
                "index": {
                    "size": {
                        "total": "0b",
                        "total_in_bytes": 0,
                        "reused": "0b",
                        "reused_in_bytes": 0,
                        "recovered": "0b",
                        "recovered_in_bytes": 0,
                        "percent": "0.0%"
                    },
                    "files": {
                        "total": 0,
                        "reused": 0,
                        "recovered": 0,
                        "percent": "0.0%"
                    },
                    "total_time": "0s",
                    "total_time_in_millis": 0,
                    "source_throttle_time": "-1",
                    "source_throttle_time_in_millis": 0,
                    "target_throttle_time": "-1",
                    "target_throttle_time_in_millis": 0
                },
                "translog": {
                    "recovered": 0,
                    "total": 0,
                    "percent": "100.0%",
                    "total_on_start": 0,
                    "total_time": "465ms",
                    "total_time_in_millis": 465
                },
                "verify_index": {
                    "check_index_time": "0s",
                    "check_index_time_in_millis": 0,
                    "total_time": "0s",
                    "total_time_in_millis": 0
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

The recovery type EMPTY_STORE is undocumented and I can't find anything but a single unanswered question in the ES forums about it. Does anyone know if the index is hosed or if I just need to wait a bit? Is there anything I can do to trigger the recovery to advance?

This is ES version 5.4.3